# LINQ - Merge two queries and exclude items from the first query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm pretty sure this falls under a "UNION" scenario but I'm really just looking for the best approach to solve my problem (even if it's not a UNION).

I have a query that looks like this:

```
var query = context.AffiliateConfigurations.Where(x => x.AffiliateId == affiliateId).Select(config => new ViewModels.ConfigurationItem
                {
                    ConfigurationId = config.AffiliateConfigurationId,
                    ConfigKey = config.ConfigKey,
                    ConfigValue = config.ConfigValue,
                    UpdatedDate = config.UpdatedDate,
                    ConfigurationType = ViewModels.ConfigurationType.Affiliate
                });
```

What I want to do is add some more results to that query. I have another table called SiteConfiguration that has the EXACT same schema but I want to add only rows from that table where the ConfigKey does not already exist in my original query.

I have something like the following currently (and it works), but I'm looking for a "pure" LINQ way to do it:

```
var items = context.AffiliateConfigurations.Where(x => x.AffiliateId == affiliateId).Select(config => new ViewModels.ConfigurationItem
    {
        ConfigurationId = config.AffiliateConfigurationId,
        ConfigKey = config.ConfigKey,
        ConfigValue = config.ConfigValue,
        UpdatedDate = config.UpdatedDate,
        ConfigurationType = ViewModels.ConfigurationType.Affiliate
        }).ToList();

var query = context.SiteConfigurations.Select(config => new ViewModels.ConfigurationItem
{
    ConfigurationId = config.SiteConfigurationId,
    ConfigKey = config.ConfigKey,
    ConfigValue = config.ConfigValue,
    UpdatedDate = config.UpdatedDate
});

foreach (var item in query)
{
    if (items.All(x => x.ConfigKey != item.ConfigKey))
    {
        items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Except()?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your Question is `"I have two collections and i want to merge them.how do i exclude items from the second collection,if the item's property is matching with another item's property on the first list."`

Yes LINQ's UNION is what you need in such scenarios

All you need to do is a Write a simple Comparer class(Implementing the IEqualityComparer interface)for your `ConfigurationItem`

```
class ConfigEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ConfigurationItem>
{

    public bool Equals(ConfigurationItem a, ConfigurationItem b)
    {
        if (a.ConfigKey == b.ConfigKey)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ConfigurationItem a)
    {
            //do some hashing here
            //int hCode = IntegerField1 ^ IntegerField2;
            return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

That is all you need.You can now run the UNION query and get your expected output.

```
 var comparer = new ConfigEqualityComparer();
 var result = Enumerable.Union<ConfigurationItem>(items, query, comparer);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the LINQ Union operator is what you want.  You just need to create an class that implements the `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface for your item.  Here is some demo code.  Try the `foreach` without the comparer to see the dupes included, or as is to have them removed.  I was running the code in LINQPad, if you're using Visual Studio you'll need to move the `Main` method into a class and call it.

```
void Main()
{
    List<DataObject> set1 = new List<DataObject>();
    List<DataObject> set2 = new List<DataObject>();

    set1.Add(new DataObject("a"));
    set1.Add(new DataObject("b"));
    set1.Add(new DataObject("c"));
    set1.Add(new DataObject("d"));
    set1.Add(new DataObject("e"));

    set2.Add(new DataObject("c"));
    set2.Add(new DataObject("d"));
    set2.Add(new DataObject("e"));
    set2.Add(new DataObject("f"));
    set2.Add(new DataObject("g"));
    set2.Add(new DataObject("h"));

    // try as  
    // foreach (DataObject d in set1.Union(set2)) {
    // and dupes will be present

    foreach (DataObject d in set1.Union(set2, new DOComparer())) {
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class DataObject {
    public DataObject(string value) {
        Value = value;
    }
    public string Value {get;private set;}

    public override string ToString() {
        return Value;
    }
}

public class DOComparer:IEqualityComparer<DataObject> {
    public bool Equals(DataObject do1, DataObject do2) {
        return do1.Value.Equals(do2.Value);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataObject d) {
        return d.Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```